# Variables in debian/rules makefile

Tags: ubuntu, rpm, dpkg

I have to port one RPM (made for Fedora) to Ubuntu as a deb package.

In the RPM .spec file I'm using several variables (`$RPM_BUILD_ROOT, %{_libdir}, %{name}, %{version}`) to create a symlink:

```
%install
...
(cd $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/%{_bindir}; ln -sf %{_libdir}/%{name}-%{version}/%{name} . )
```

(Relative symlinks are forbidden (please don't ask why) -- that is why `ln` command looks strange.)

So, what are equivalents of those variables in `debian/rules` makefile?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Aside: This seems like something that the upstream Makefile ought to be doing, instead of the downstream packaging.)

Depends on which framework you're using for your `rules` file.

In [CDBS](http://build-common.alioth.debian.org/), something like this should work...

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f

include /usr/share/cdbs/1/rules/debhelper.mk
# probably what you want (automagic happens),
# but I don't know details of your package
#include /usr/share/cdbs/1/class/automake.mk

DEBVERS := $(shell dpkg-parsechangelog | sed -n -e 's/^Version: //p')
VERSION := $(shell echo '$(DEBVERS)' | sed -e 's/^[[:digit:]]*://' -e 's/[~-].*//')

install/$(DEB_ALL_PACKAGES)::
        dh_link -p$(cdbs_curpkg) \
                /usr/lib/$(cdbs_curpkg)-$(VERSION)/$(cdbs_curpkg) \
                /usr/bin/$(cdbs_curpkg)
```

If you have a better way of getting the version (say, `$(shell cat version.txt))`), use it.  The Debian version is not always the source package version; here, I strip out the epoch and packaging version, if any, but this isn't always correct.

Other CDBS classes might define `$${libdir}` and `$${bindir}`, but I haven't seen anything common.

Note that `dh_link` will make relative links if possible, even when given absolute paths.  If this is a problem, you might have to resort to something really nasty like

```
        cd debian/$(cdbs_curpkg) && ln -s ...
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I was using just a skeleton from dh_make. CDBS looks quite interesting.

Comment: `dh_make -b` will give you a skeleton CDBS rules.

Answer (score 2):

In newer versions of dpkg (1.17.0+), you can get the full version with:

```
DEBVER := $(shell dpkg-parsechangelog -SVersion)
```

And there's no need to use sed to extract the parts, assuming you have `SHELL := /bin/bash`.  Just use bash string interpolation like so:

```
DEBVERSION := $(shell debver="$(DEBVER)"; echo "$${debver%-*}")
```